# How to mask value when logged by using @ToString annotation or by creating new annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I would like to create my own custom annotation, i'm using Spring framework.

when someone annotate his POJO class a code behind will trigger methods.

For example @Sensetive(values = "accountNumber")
when annotate on below class

```
public class User {
   protected String user = "";
   protected String code = "";
   protected String accountNumber = "";
}
```

will call a method that when logging the values they will appear masked ( for example accountNumber = "12345" -> masked accountNumber = XXXX5).

I'm aware of @ToString annotation that can exclude the value completely when calling toString method, but is there possibility to mask it?

Comment: Usually u setup global layout configuration for masking sensitive information. You didnt mention what logging provider you use. Take this link for example for logback https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277930/mask-sensitive-data-in-logs-with-logback

Comment: Thanks! that is the solution for my issue.

Answer (score -2):

You can just override `toString` method and mask the account number in it, e.g.:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    String maskedAccountNumber = accountNumber.replaceAll("[0-9]+", "*"); //This is just an example, actual implementation might differ
    return "user : " + user +
        " code : " + code +
        " account number : " + maskedAccountNumber;
}
```

All the logging/printing methods (e.g. `System.out.println`) will call `toString` of respective object so having this method overridden will help mask the details.

Comment: thanks for the response but i was looking for more generic solution for all classes and not just for the specific one.

Comment: @SamP. well, all classes will have different members and different masking rules. So generic solution might not be ideal.