# How to block the middle four digits of the mobile phone number with Java?

Tags: java, expression

When the log is printed, I want to block the middle of the phone number and ID card. I don't want to change the toString method in each entity class.Is there some way to replace the phone number from a long String ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277930/mask-sensitive-data-in-logs-with-logback

Comment: What logging framework do you use?

Comment: We use the logback framework.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some success by decorating the object you're logging with a wrapper that is aware of the sensitivities of various fields.

A very basic example...

```
class NumberHidingDecorator {

    private final Object decorated;

    public NumberHidingDecorator(Object decorated) {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return decorated.toString().replaceAll("(\d{2})\d+(\d{2})", "$1...$2");
    }
}
```

And pass the decorated object to your logging facility

```
log.info("Invalid credit card {}", new NumberHidingDecorator(creditCard));
```

Comment: Thank you , but I want do something in the logger class but not the place of logging, because there is a lot of entity need to be decorated.