# Springboot-Logback: Mask SSN last four Digits

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I am trying to mask sensitive information like SSN and Credit card in my Spring boot application using Logback.xml. I searched various links in web, but could not find good solution.Is there a simple-way or any library to mask the sensitive information in logs?

**Input**

```
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","SSN":123456789}
```

output:

```
  {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","SSN":12345****}
```

And found this on stack overflow but trouble figuring out regex.Any help would be greatly appreciated

[Mask sensitive data in logs with logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277930/mask-sensitive-data-in-logs-with-logback)

Comment: please check: https://www.schibsted.pl/blog/logback-pattern-gdpr/

Comment: @dassum Tried already but no luck not sure regex mentioned in example is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`String.ReplaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). The regex would want to just match the first 5 digits of the SSN, keep them, and replace everything else. Since we know that every SSN is only 9 digits, just capture the first 5 like so:

```
String rgx = "([0-9]{5})[0-9]*";
```

We capture the first 5 in a group, we can then reference that group in `ReplaceAll()` with `$1`. We don't care how many digits are after it, so just use `[0-9]*` to match the rest. After we reference the first 5 digits with `$1`, just replace everything else with `****`.

The result:

```
String baseSSN = "123456789";    
String rgx = "([0-9]{5})[0-9]*";
String modifiedSSN = baseSSN.ReplaceAll(rgx, "$1****"); //modifiedSSN = 12345****
```

You can mess with the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/vds9Sv/1).

Comment: How can I mask entire SSN or Even FirstName=********* without giving digits?

Comment: If you just want to mask everything in a string, just do `str.ReplaceAll(".*", "************")`. The regex `.` matches anything except a line break, and the `*` matches it 0 or more times. Thus it will replace anything you pass in with any number of asterisks.